# NPM install not work and make lock-json file

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, npm-start, npm-init

Hi I'm trying to install npm to run a kit.

my node version is: v12.18.3
my npm version is: 6.14.6

my folder is "test" and I'm installing npm with this command:

Kian@DESKTOP-CL16DA7 MINGW64 /d/markitdone/test
**$ npm install**

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\markitdone\test\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\markitdone\test\package.json'
npm WARN test No description
npm WARN test No repository field.
npm WARN test No README data
npm WARN test No license field.

up to date in 0.845s
found 0 vulnerabilities

[image]

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Before you use npm install.

You need to create a project, either React, Vue.js or Angular in your test directory