# How to fix npm error file not found for vs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

First of all I am trying to create a localhost and the first line of code of the script is below:

```
npm install -g json-server
```

However, there is no such thing as npm in my vs code, I have node.js downloaded which includes the npm. I think i have to install it into vs code but I'm not sure, the error message i get is this:

```
C:\Users\kiera\OneDrive\Desktop\myfile>npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\kiera\OneDrive\Desktop\myfile/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kiera\OneDrive\Desktop\myfile\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I'm pretty new to js but this has completely thrown me off, I don't have a clue what it means or how to fix it, I have looked through numerous explanations but nothing seems to be working, nor do I know if I'm doing anything correctly.

An understanding of this would help very much and a solution to fix this error so I can start my script!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the `myfile` folder contain a package.json file? If not, why not? Try creating one using `npm init`

Comment: it opens up a package-lock.json file. What does this mean?

Comment: What do you mean? What opens "package-lock.json file"?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71726546/npm-install-not-work-and-make-lock-json-file